# Byte shifiting under msvc

Tags: visual-c++, gcc, integer, byte

I have a buffer where the first 4 bytes represents an unsigned 32bit integer.
The buffer looks like this {32, 0, 0, 0, ...}

The following code works under gcc without any problems:

```
uint32_t size = buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8) | (buffer[2] << 16) | (buffer[3] << 24);
```

Size is 32 as expected but if i compile the project with msvc size is 538976288 instead of 32.

What is the problem?

EDIT:
full source code for test:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int pos = 0;
    uint32_t buffer [] = {32, 0, 0, 0};
    uint32_t size = buffer[pos++] | (buffer[pos++] << 8) | (buffer[pos++] << 16) | (buffer[pos++] << 24) ;
    printf("size=%d\n", size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 538976288 is what you get if you put 32 in all four bytes, would there be any reason for that to happen?

Comment: Only if it make a problem to use pos++ in the index of the array. e.g

    buffer[pos++] | (buffer[pos++] << 8) | (buffer[pos++] << 16) | (buffer[pos++] << 24)

Comment: Yes, that's a problem, don't do it

Comment: Microsoft makes me laughing again... Thanks

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior